# Using startswith in lambda expression and filter function with Python

Tags: python, list, function, filter, lambda

I'm trying to find the words starting with character "s". I have a list of strings (seq) to check.

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']

sseq = " ".join(seq)

filtered = lambda x: True if sseq.startswith('s') else False

filtered_list = filter(filtered, seq)

print('Words are:')
for a in filtered_list:
    print(a)
```

The output is:

```
Words are:
soup
dog
salad
cat
great
```

Where I see the entire list. How can I use lambda and filter() method to return the words starting with "s" ? Thank you

Comment: Why not just use a simple list comprehension?  After all, Python is all about doing things simply.  :-)

Comment: `[word for word in seq if word.lower().startswith('s')]`

Comment: Why does `filtered` ignore its argument?

Comment: Why are you using `sseq` in the function, instead of `x`, the argument? Why are you creating `sseq` in the first place?

Comment: Also, as an aside, *don't assign lambda expressions to a name*. If you are going to do that, **just use a full function definition**

Comment: Also, `True if sseq.startswith('s') else False` is needlessly wordy and redundant. `sseq.startswith('s')` already returns a bool, so in general, `True if boolean_condition else False` should just be `boolean_condition`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, all very insightful for a beginner. I also prefer list comprehension, better to follow simpler approaches but this was a part of an assignment. I also want to get use to using lambda functions during code development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your filter lambda always just checks what your joined word starts with, not the letter you pass in.

```
filtered = lambda x: x.startswith('s')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']
result = list(filter(lambda x: (x[0] == 's'), seq)) 
print(result)
```

or

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']
result = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('s'),seq))
print(result)
```

both output

```
['soup', 'salad']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another elegant method if you're okay with not using `filter`:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in seq if x.startswith('s')]
print('Words are: '+ " , ".join(filtered_list))
```

Output:

```
Words are: soup , salad
```